# How to request access to a user's Facebook Page through business manager?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to assign a systemuser of my application to a `Page` with the `Advertiser` role as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/smb/system-user-access-token-handling/v3.0:

```
curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/<PAGE_ID>/roles?admin_id=<USER_ID>&role=Advertiser&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

When I try this with my data and access_token I get this error message:

> (#200) Either app or user doesn't have permission to modify admins.

The problem is, that the infos provided on the info-page are very sparse and I have no clue what the required special permissions are and where to get them:

> Assigning permissions to a page from the API requires special permissions. Please reach out to your Facebook rep if you require this feature.

The application currently has permissions for:
* `email`
* `manage_pages`
* `pages_show_list`
* `publish_pages`
* `ads_management`
* `ads_read`
* `business_management`
* `public_profile`

Comment: did you try system user access token?

Comment: @mdeora yes, I tried every `access_token` combination I could imagine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem.
The documentation at the [The SMB Integration Playbook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/smb/system-user-access-token-handling/v3.0) does not help though...

Instead you have to use a combination of two steps:

1. [Claim the Client Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/assets/#pages-claim)
2. [Give Pages Access to your System User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/assets/#pages-permission)